# Puppeteer wait for all images to load then take screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

I am using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to try to take a screenshot of a website after all images have loaded but can't get it to work.

Here is the code I've got so far, I am using https://www.digg.com as the example website:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.digg.com/');

    await page.setViewport({width: 1640, height: 800});

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));
    });

    await page.waitFor(1000);

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

        function preLoad() {

            var promises = [];

            function loadImage(img) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                    if (img.complete) {
                        resolve(img)
                    }
                    img.onload = function() {
                        resolve(img);
                    };
                    img.onerror = function(e) {
                        resolve(img);
                    };
                })
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
            {
                promises.push(loadImage(images[i]));
            }

            return Promise.all(promises);
        }

        return preLoad();
    });

    await page.screenshot({path: 'digg.png', fullPage: true});

    browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: ive tried basically all of the solutions and they work for Img elements, but they don't work for background-image css.... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296599/puppeteer-screenshot-full-page-omitting-background-images

Comment: I was able to overcome this issue only with the [solution linked by Seth Townsend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61304202/14342270).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There is a [built-in option](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v18.2.1/docs/api/puppeteer.page.goto.md#remarks) for that:

```
await page.goto('https://www.digg.com/', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
```

> `networkidle0` - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least 500 ms

> `networkidle2` - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms.

Of course it won't work if you're working with endless-scrolling-single-page-applications like Twitter.

[Puppeteer GitHub issue #1552](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1552) provides explanation for the motivation behind `networkidle2`.

Comment: In case of digg.com some of the images are loaded only when you scroll down, do you know of a way to wait for the images to load after scrolling?

Comment: I guess your solution will work, but - after studying how digg's home page works - I'll say you have to scroll little by little, whereas in your code you jump by almost a full page. Look in the source - there are lots of lazy-loading images that will only load if in the viewport.

Comment: I think it should be: { waitUntil: "networkidle" } instead of {"waitUntil" : "networkidle"}

Comment: In the latest puppeteer builds `networkidle` is deprecated and replaced with

`networkidle0` & `networkidle2`

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegobackoptions

Comment: Hi, everytime i click something it would load stuff, how can i wait for the next network idle , but there isn't any goto you see cuz it's a button click.

Comment: Its loading image tags but not loading css background-images... any solution there?

Answer (score 30):

Another option, actually evaluate to get callback when all images were loaded

This option will also work with [setContent](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcontenthtml) that doesn't support the wait `networkidle0` option

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const selectors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img"));
  await Promise.all(selectors.map(img => {
    if (img.complete) return;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      img.addEventListener('load', resolve);
      img.addEventListener('error', reject);
    });
  }));
})
```

Comment: Note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yea but it's event emitter, npm that promisify it won't do exactly the same?, +thanks for the good edit

Comment: You can't promisify `EventTarget`s automatically yet as far as I know - but the rest doesn't need `new Promise` :)

Comment: Note that unlike `networkidle` this will wait for all the images based on tags present in the DOM when the `evaluate` is called. So if scripts add more images asynchronously this won't work (you can in theory call it recursively but... meh).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, notice that on `setContent` for example, you can't use `networkidle`, at least not in a way I found

Comment: FYI this answer is out of date. `setContent` supports `waitUntil` now, which is very helpful.

Comment: @brainbag During an experimentation, I found that `setContent` with `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'` will take as twice as long as `goto` with the same option. This is weird, because with out the option, then `setContent` will be faster than `goto`.

Comment: this waits for img query selectors, what about block elements with images that load via css or elements that load images with javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296599/puppeteer-screenshot-full-page-omitting-background-images

Answer (score 12):

#### Wait for Lazy Loading Images

You may want to consider scrolling down first using a method such as [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to account for lazy loading images:

```
await page.goto('https://www.digg.com/', {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle0', // Wait for all non-lazy loaded images to load
});

await page.evaluate(async () => {
  // Scroll down to bottom of page to activate lazy loading images
  document.body.scrollIntoView(false);

  // Wait for all remaining lazy loading images to load
  await Promise.all(Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), image => {
    if (image.complete) {
      return;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      image.addEventListener('load', resolve);
      image.addEventListener('error', reject);
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: Hi Grant, This doesn't fetch all the images. For example, try for the URL given 
https://www.insight.com/en_US/search.html?qtype=all&q=HP%20Printers

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is applicable to multiple sites using the **page.setViewPort(...)** method as given below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async(() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true, // Set to false while development
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--start-maximized', // Start in maximized state
        ],
    });

    const page = await = browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.digg.com/', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0
    });

    // Get scroll width and height of the rendered page and set viewport
    const bodyWidth = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollWidth);
    const bodyHeight = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollHeight);
    await page.setViewport({ width: bodyWidth, height: bodyHeight });

    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'digg-example.png' });
})();
```

Comment: `waitFor` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release: see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214 for details.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the exact same issue.
I have a feeling the solution will involve using:

```
await page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled(true);

page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    //some code here that adds this request to ...
    //a list and checks whether all list items have ...
    //been successfully completed!
});
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionenabledvalue

Comment: It should be possible to achieve it using promises only.