# Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am working on creating PDF from web page.

The application on which I am working is single page application.

I tried many options and suggestion on https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1412

But it is not working

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    headless: true,
    devtools: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(fullUrl, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
});

await page.type('#username', 'scott');
await page.type('#password', 'tiger');

await page.click('#Login_Button');
await page.waitFor(2000);

await page.pdf({
    path: outputFileName,
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    headerTemplate: '',
    footerTemplate: '',
    printBackground: true,
    format: 'A4'
});
```

What I want is to generate PDF report as soon as Page is loaded completely.

I don't want to write any type of delays i.e.   await page.waitFor(2000);

I can not do waitForSelector because the page has charts and graphs which are rendered after calculations.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I  have tried all suggested solutions. With Node.js puppeteer nothing worked. I switched to a Python script to do load the HTML, wait some seconds for the JS to load external elements / generate graphs, and then generate the PDF.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) to wait for the new page to load completely before generating a PDF:

```
await page.goto(fullUrl, {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
});

await page.type('#username', 'scott');
await page.type('#password', 'tiger');

await page.click('#Login_Button');

await page.waitForNavigation({
  waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
});

await page.pdf({
  path: outputFileName,
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: '',
  footerTemplate: '',
  printBackground: true,
  format: 'A4',
});
```

If there is a certain element that is generated dynamically that you would like included in your PDF, consider using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to ensure that the content is visible:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#example', {
  visible: true,
});
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for the signal 'networkidle0'?

Comment: 'networkidle0' is documented here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

Comment: Should `page.waitForSelector` be called after `page.goto` or before? Could you answer a similar question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909236/pupeteer-script-does-not-wait-for-the-selector-to-get-loaded-and-i-get-a-blank-h ?

Comment: Why would I use networkidle0 when I could use the default load event? Is it faster to use networkidle0?

Comment: If you're clicking something that triggers navigation, there's a race condition if [`Promise.all isn't used`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options), e.g. `Promise.all([page.click(...), page.waitForNavigation(...)])`

Comment: @Gary See [this comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1666#issuecomment-354224942) by a (former) core Puppeteer developer.

Comment: I had same Problems. I use format: "A4".  My Solution was not to use the scale (<1) option.

Comment: page.waitForNavigation() &  page.waitForSelector() link are dead

Comment: > - `networkidle0` : consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least `500` ms. 
> https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.goto/#remarks 
> https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.puppeteerlifecycleevent/

Answer (score 130):

Sometimes the `networkidle` events do not always give an indication that the page has completely loaded. There could still be a few **JS** `scripts` modifying the content on the page. So watching for the completion of `HTML` source code modifications by the browser seems to be yielding better results. Here's a function you could use -

```
const waitTillHTMLRendered = async (page, timeout = 30000) => {
  const checkDurationMsecs = 1000;
  const maxChecks = timeout / checkDurationMsecs;
  let lastHTMLSize = 0;
  let checkCounts = 1;
  let countStableSizeIterations = 0;
  const minStableSizeIterations = 3;

  while(checkCounts++ <= maxChecks){
    let html = await page.content();
    let currentHTMLSize = html.length; 

    let bodyHTMLSize = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML.length);

    console.log('last: ', lastHTMLSize, ' <> curr: ', currentHTMLSize, " body html size: ", bodyHTMLSize);

    if(lastHTMLSize != 0 && currentHTMLSize == lastHTMLSize) 
      countStableSizeIterations++;
    else 
      countStableSizeIterations = 0; //reset the counter

    if(countStableSizeIterations >= minStableSizeIterations) {
      console.log("Page rendered fully..");
      break;
    }

    lastHTMLSize = currentHTMLSize;
    await page.waitForTimeout(checkDurationMsecs);
  }  
};
```

You could use this after the page `load` / `click` function call and before you process the page content. e.g.

```
await page.goto(url, {'timeout': 10000, 'waitUntil':'load'});
await waitTillHTMLRendered(page)
const data = await page.content()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer hasn't gotten more "love".  In reality, a lot of the time we really just need to make sure JavaScript is done messing with the page before we scrape it.  Network events don't accomplish this, and if you have dynamically generated content, there isn't always something you can reliably do a "waitForSelector/visible:true" on

Comment: Thanks @roberto - btw I just updated the answer, you could use this with the 'load' event rather than 'networkidle2' . Thought it would be little more optimal with that. I have tested this in production and can confirm it works well too!

Comment: I tried to put the `checkDurationMsecs` to 200ms, and the bodyHTMLSize keep changing, and give huge numbers, I am using electron and rect also, very strange.

Comment: Ok I found that ridiculous hard to catch bug. If your luck manage to catch that 100k long html page, you realize there are CSS classes like `CodeMirror`, must be https://codemirror.net/ , meaning.... `document.body.innerHTML` is catching the dev console too ! Just remove `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();` for e2e testing. I hope don't get any more bad surprise.

Comment: This was the answer for rendering large HTML files out to PDF using Puppeteer and PagedJS. The pagedJS polyfill was still faffing with the content once network traffic stopped so the pdf request was kicking off without all of the content rendered. Thank you.

Comment: this is the **only** way when dealing with dynamically rendered pages. networkidle events cannot be used for this reliably.

Answer (score 54):

In some cases, the best solution for me was:

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
```

---

Some other options you could try are:

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

You can check this at puppeteer documentation:
https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v11.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions

Comment: This doesn't ensure that any scripts loaded have finished executing. Therefore HTML could still be rendering and this would proceed.

Comment: For those who are confused by these options, `domcontentloaded` is the first one to fire, so you generally use it when you want to move on with your script before any external resources load. Typically, this is because you don't want data from them. `load`, `networkidle2` and `networkidle0` offer different flavors of waiting for resources in roughly increasing strictness, but none of them provide an exact guarantee that "the page is loaded" (because this varies from site to site, so it's ill-defined in general).

Comment: Does this work with `page.click` ?

Answer (score 40):

I always like to wait for **selectors**, as many of them are a great indicator that the page has fully loaded:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#blue-button');
```

Comment: You are a genius, this is such an obvious solution, especially when you are waiting for specific elements, and as soon as I did not guess myself, thank you!

Comment: @Arch4Arts you should create your own clicking function that does the waiting for you as well as clicking

Answer (score 11):

In the latest Puppeteer version, `networkidle2` worked for me:

```js
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

Answer (score 10):

Wrap the `page.click` and `page.waitForNavigation` in a Promise.all

```
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('#submit_button'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
  ]);
```

Comment: `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })` is this same as `page
.waitForNetworkIdle()`?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue with `networkidle` when I was working on an offscreen renderer. I needed a WebGL-based engine to finish rendering and only then make a screenshot. What worked for me was a [page.waitForFunction()](https://www.tools4testing.com/contents/puppeteer/puppeteer-waitforfunction) method. In my case the usage was as follows:

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForFunction("renderingCompleted === true")
const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({});
```

In the rendering code, I was simply setting the `renderingCompleted` variable to true, when done. If you don't have access to the page code you can use some other existing identifier.

Answer (score 6):

Answers so far haven't mentioned a critical fact: it's impossible to write a one-size-fits-all `waitUntilPageLoaded` function that works on every page. If it were possible, Puppeteer would surely provide it.

Such a function can't rely on a timeout, because there's always some page that takes longer to load than that timeout. As you extend the timeout to reduce the failure rate, you introduce unnecessary delays when working with fast pages. Timeouts are generally a poor solution, opting out of Puppeteer's event-driven model.

Waiting for idle network requests might not always work if the responses involve long-running DOM updates that take longer than 500ms to trigger a render.

Waiting for the DOM to stop changing might miss slow network requests,  long-delayed JS triggers, or ongoing DOM manipulation that might cause the listener never to settle, unless specially handled.

And, of course, there's user interaction: captchas, prompts and cookie/subscription modals that need to be clicked through and dismissed before the page is in a sensible state for a full-page screenshot (for example).

Since every page has different, arbitrary JS behavior, the typical approach is to write event-driven logic that works for a *specific* page. Making precise, directed assumptions is much better than cobbling together a boatload of hacks that tries to solve every edge case.

If your use case *is* to write a load event that works on every page, my suggestion is to use some combination of the tools described here that is most balanced to meet your needs (speed vs. accuracy, development time/code complexity vs accuracy, etc). Use fail-safes for everything rather than blindly assuming all pages will cooperate with your assumptions. Think hard about what extent you really need to try to handle every web page. Prepare to compromise and accept some degree of failures you can live with.

---

Here's a quick rundown of the strategies you can mix and match to wait for loads to fit your needs:

[`page.goto()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) and [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) default to the `load` event, which "is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)), but this is often too pessimistic; there's no need to wait for a ton of data you don't care about. Often the data is available without waiting for all external resources, so `domcontentloaded` should be faster. See my post [Avoiding Puppeteer Antipatterns](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) for further discussion.

On the other hand, if there are JS-triggered networks requests after `load`, you'll miss that data. Hence `networkidle2` and `networkidle0`, which wait 500 ms after the number of active network requests are 2 or 0. The motivation for the 2 version is that some sites keep ongoing requests open, which would cause `networkidle0` to time out.

If you're waitng for a specific network response that might have a payload (or, for the general case, implementing your own network idle monitor), use [`page.waitForResponse()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options). [`page.waitForRequest()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforrequesturlorpredicate-options), [`page.waitForNetworkIdle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornetworkidleoptions) and `page.on("request", ...)` are also useful here.

If you're waiting for a particular selector to be visible, use [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options). If you're waiting for a load on a specific page, identify a selector that indicates the state you want to wait for. Generally speaking, for scripts specific to one page, this is the main tool to wait for the state you want, whether you're extracting data or clicking something. Frames and shadow roots thwart this function.

[`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) lets you wait for an arbitrary predicate, for example, checking that the page's HTML or a specific list is a certain length. It's also useful for quickly dipping into frames and shadow roots to wait for predicates that depend on nested state. This function is also handy for detecting DOM mutations.

The most general tool is [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), which plugs code into the browser. You can put just about any conditions you want here; most other Puppeteer functions are convenience wrappers for common cases you could implement by hand with `evaluate`.

---

See also [When is the page loaded?](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#when-is-the-page-loaded) in the Playwright docs (yes, it's not Puppeteer, but the tool is very similar, and this part of the docs pertains to both libraries):

> Modern pages perform numerous activities after the load event was fired. They fetch data lazily, populate UI, load expensive resources, scripts and styles after the load event was fired. There is no way to tell that the page is loaded, it depends on the page, framework, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use to ensure all elements have rendered

```
await page.waitFor('*')
```

Reference: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1875

Comment: `waitFor` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214 for details and how to migrate your code.

Answer (score 4):

As for December 2020, `waitFor` function is deprecated, as the warning inside the code tell:

> waitFor is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214 for details and how
> to migrate your code.

You can use:

```
sleep(millisecondsCount) {
    if (!millisecondsCount) {
        return;
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millisecondsCount)).catch();
}
```

And use it:

```
(async () => {
    await sleep(1000);
})();
```

Comment: just use page.waitForTimeout(1000)

Comment: The github issue states that they just deprecated the "magic" waitFor function. You can still use one of the specific waitFor*() functions. Hence your sleep() code is needless. (Not to mention that it’s overcomplicated for what it does, and it’s generally a bad idea to tackle concurrency problems with programmatic timeouts.)

Answer (score 4):

Keeping in mind [the caveat that there's no silver bullet to handle all page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535642/6243352), one strategy is to monitor the DOM until it's been stable (i.e. has not seen a mutation) for more than `n` milliseconds. This is similar to the network idle solution but geared towards the DOM rather than requests and therefore covers a different subset of loading behaviors.

Generally, this code would follow a `page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})` or `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})`, but you could also wait for it alongside, say, [`waitForNetworkIdle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.2.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornetworkidleoptions) using `Promise.all()` or `Promise.race()`.

Here's a simple example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^14.3.0

const waitForDOMStable = (
  page,
  options={timeout: 30000, idleTime: 2000}
) =>
  page.evaluate(({timeout, idleTime}) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.disconnect();
        const msg = `timeout of ${timeout} ms ` +
          "exceeded waiting for DOM to stabilize";
        reject(Error(msg));
      }, timeout);
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(finish, idleTime);
      });
      const config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      };
      observer.observe(document.body, config);
      const finish = () => {
        observer.disconnect();
        resolve();
      };
      let timeoutId = setTimeout(finish, idleTime);
    }),
    options
  )
;

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<title>test</title></head><body><h1></h1><script>
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.querySelector("h1").textContent += i + " ";
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }
})();
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await waitForDOMStable(page);
  console.log(await page.$eval("h1", el => el.textContent));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

For pages that continually mutate the DOM more often than the `idle` value, the timeout will eventually trigger and reject the promise, following the typical Puppeteer fallback. You can set a more aggressive overall timeout to fit your needs or tailor the logic to ignore (or only monitor) a particular subtree.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave comments, but I made a python version of Anand's answer for anyone who finds it useful (i.e. if they use pyppeteer).

```
async def waitTillHTMLRendered(page: Page, timeout: int = 30000): 
    check_duration_m_secs = 1000
    max_checks = timeout / check_duration_m_secs
    last_HTML_size = 0
    check_counts = 1
    count_stable_size_iterations = 0
    min_stabe_size_iterations = 3

    while check_counts <= max_checks:
        check_counts += 1
        html = await page.content()
        currentHTMLSize = len(html); 

        if(last_HTML_size != 0 and currentHTMLSize == last_HTML_size):
            count_stable_size_iterations += 1
        else:
            count_stable_size_iterations = 0 # reset the counter

        if(count_stable_size_iterations >= min_stabe_size_iterations):
            break
    

        last_HTML_size = currentHTMLSize
        await page.waitFor(check_duration_m_secs)
```

Comment: This should go in a pyppeteer question, not a puppeteer question.

Comment: This is not relevant because it is not for Puppeteer / JS

Answer (score 0):

For me the `{ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' }` is always my go to.
I found that `networkidle` doesnt work well...

Answer (score 0):

waitfornetworkidle() worked for me: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfornetworkidle

I don't know why no one has mentioned it yet. If there's an actual reason then, please share.

Comment: `page.goto({waitUntil: "networkidle0"})` already waits for network idle, so tossing in another is probably spurious.

Answer (score 0):

Completely loaded can mean a lot of different things.
Wait for all images to be loaded maybe?

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => ![...document.querySelectorAll('img')].find(i => !i.complete))
```

Comment: `![...document.querySelectorAll('img')].find(i => !i.complete)` could be clearer as `[...document.querySelectorAll('img')].every(e => e.complete)`