# Node puppeteer generate cookie after final page lands (After all redirections complete)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

My puppeteer script is landing on one page but there may be some internal redirection and i want to generate cookie after final page lands. So i have put some await timeout so i can make sure that my page is landed.

I also generate screenshot and i see my page 
Here is a code. Sometimes it is generating false cookie.

```
async function main(proxy) {

    let promiseArray = [];

    let chromeOptions = {
        headless: true,
        slowMo:10,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [
            `--proxy-server=${proxy}`,
        ]
    };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    let finalCookie = '';

    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +
        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';

    // **This is page load event**
    promiseArray.push(new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        await page.on('load', async function () {
            let cookies = await page.cookies();
            console.log("START==================================");

            console.log(await page.url());

            let cookieArray = [];

            cookies.forEach(function (item) {
                cookieArray.push(item.name + '='+item.value);
            });

            finalCookie = cookieArray.join(';');

            console.log('END');

            resolve();
        });
    }));


    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

    // const page = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    await page.authenticate({ username: 'spopov', password: '68LYCfVy' });

    url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];

    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
        timeout: 0
    });

    let filename = 'screenshots/'+ proxy + '-1.png';

    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('#someid');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in cookie generation");
        await page.screenshot({path: filename});
    }

    await page.screenshot({path: filename});

    await timeout(3000);
    filename = 'screenshots/'+ proxy + '-2.png';

    await page.screenshot({path: filename});

    await browser.close();

    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .then(async (result) => {
            let cookies = await page.cookies();
            let cookieArray = [];

            cookies.forEach(function (item) {
                cookieArray.push(item.name + '='+item.value);
            });

            finalCookie = cookieArray.join(';');

            return finalCookie;
        });
};
```

I want to make sure when my cookie is generated page is fully loaded and i get correct cookie.

const timeout = millis => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));

Comment: Do you know which URL you'll eventually wind up on, or a selector or some other condition that determines when you're on the right page? If not, the problem may evaluate to [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/72535642#72535642). There are a variety of antipatterns and issues in the code, like `await page.on` (`page.on` doesn't return a promise), sleeping, using an [explicit promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743) where none is required (`goto` already unblocks on the `'load'` event), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.16.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions):

```js
// Navigate to desired page...

await page.waitForNavigation();

// Generate cookie...
```