# Pupeteer execute command in Devtools Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

So I have an line which I can just paste manually into the Devtools Console in a browser. Is there any way to make pupeteer execute it? After searching I havent found anything, sorry if this has been answered already, I am quite new.

For those who care its an Line to buy an listing of an Item, Example:

BuyMarketListing('listing', '3555030760772417847', 730, '2', '24716958303')

Comment: Why would you need to run it in the console *specifically* when a huge core concept of Puppeteer is to allow you to run any arbitrary JavaScript you want/need directly…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a javascript code in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610018/how-to-execute-a-javascript-code-in-puppeteer)

Comment: I cant get this line to get executed thats the problem

Comment: Then why not make your question about that and include your code as a [mre], per [ask]?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for `page.evaluate()`. [Here is a link to the Puppeteer's documentation for it](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.2&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args). You can pass in a string or an anonymous function containing the lines you want to evaluate in the page.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  await page.evaluate(() => { insert lines here }); // page.evaluate() should run the lines in the browser console

  await browser.close();
})();
```