# Pupeteer execute command in Devtools Console with await

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i have a little problems to collect a data from a webpage, but i found a way to collect them and i need execute on Devtools `await function("lero lero")`. I know i can use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) and use [evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869857/pupeteer-execute-command-in-devtools-console) but when i use `await` i receive `undefined`.

But i execute on DevTools and works: [image]

How i can execute and receive the same value.

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('localhost:3000');

  const s = await page.evaluate(async () => { "await nindo(this.endpoint)" }); 

  console.log(s);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: are you using `eval` in the DevTools console?

Comment: no, i'm not using ```eval```  @EricFortis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the first await:

```
const html = await page.evaluate(() => fetch(someUrl).then(r => r.text()))
```

Comment: like this?
``` const html = await page.evaluate(() => fetch('localhost:3000').then(r => "await nindo(this.endpoint)")); ```

i received on html this: "await nindo(this.endpoint)"

Comment: I was just giving an example of something I know works, you can replace the fetch with nindo