# Waiting for site to fully load

Tags: puppeteer, delay

I'm experimenting with JavaScript and puppeteer and when I go onto a site I have set it up so it takes a screenshot, but the problem is some elements of the website haven't loaded in when it takes the screenshot, is there anything I can do to add a delay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a function when page has fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/how-to-execute-a-function-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: I tried deploying it in my code couldn't get it to work. The error I got was that window is not defined and i have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57677369/10251383

Try this options with your page.goto():

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! networkidle0 was the one that did the job for me.