# why puppeteer does not type in some inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, screen-scraping, browser-automation

Somtimes puppeteer does not type in some input fields, to be specific, I tried to simply type something in a website's input filed called "https://webtor.io/", which has a single huge input field, I hope someone could help me with that specific example.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://webtor.io/');
   await page.type(`input[type="text"]`, 'something', { delay: 50 })
})();
```

Comment: Try to first `await page.waitForSelector('input[type="text"]');` before page.type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you go to the page the page has render the html and load up scripts, which ends up causing the delay and sometimes the text input is not loaded hence the fail.

```
  await page.goto(''https://webtor.io/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```

Check out this link for further details.
[Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded)