# Puppeteer pdf image not rendering correctly

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am generating a PDF from html markup using puppeteer and it prints a logo at the top of the page, so just a single image which isn't very big. This image is fetched from a CDN.

The issue is that a lot of times the image is not rendered properly. Sometimes it is fine but like I say, a lot of times it isn't. I don't know if this is because the image has not fully downloaded by the time the PDF has generated or what the issue could be. I have attached 2 images, one where it rendered correctly and the other when it doesn't.

Here is the code where I generate the PDF and send it to the CDN. So, the image for the PDF is fetched from the CDN and the PDF file itself is sent to the CDN.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(pdfTemplate(invoice), {
  waitUntil: "networkidle2",
});

const screenshot = await page.pdf({
  encoding: "binary",
});
await browser.close();

let cld_upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
  {
    folder: "documents",
    public_id: invoiceId,
  },
  function (error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(201).json({
      secure_url: result.secure_url,
      public_id: result.public_id,
    });
  }
);
streamifier.createReadStream(screenshot).pipe(cld_upload_stream);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: networkidle2 means 2 requests can still be outstanding when the page is considered done loading and the promise resolves. Maybe try something stricter, like networkidle0, for starters. See [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded) for more strategies.

Comment: @ggorlen so far your suggestion of changing to networkidle0 appears to be working! I will keep testing but so far so good. Thanks so much!