# Puppeteer evaluate function on load to show alert

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, puppeteer, headless

I am a newbie in puppeteer and I can't understand why the following code cannot work. any explanation would be appreciated.

```js
const puppeteer=require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://bet254.com');
    await page.evaluate(async ()=> {
        window.addEventListener("load",(event)=>{
            document.alert("Loaded!");
        })
    });

})();
```

I was expecting an alert after loading. But nothing happened! How can I add a listener to show an alert on page load?

Comment: put your IIFE in try/catch block and check for any errors you might be getting.

Comment: I got no errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.goto` already waits for the page to load, so by the time your `evalute` runs, you can't re-wait for the page to load, so the `load` event will never fire.

Another problem is that `document.alert` isn't a function. You may be thinking of `document.write` or `window.alert`. In any case, neither function is particularly useful for debugging, so I suggest sticking to `console.log` unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

When working with Puppeteer, it's important to isolate problems by running your `evaluate` code by hand in the browser without Puppeteer, otherwise you might have no idea whether it's Puppeteer or the browser code that's failing.

Anything logged in `evaluate` won't be shown in your Node stdout or stderr, so you'll probably want to monitor that with a [log listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th). You'll need to look at both Node and the browser console for errors.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument(pageFunction[, ...args])`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) will let you attach code to evaluate whenever you navigate, which might be what you're trying for here.

Here's an example of alerting headfully:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener("load", event => {
      alert("Loaded!");
    });
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "load"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Using `console.log` headlessly, with the log redirected to Node:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const onPageConsole = msg =>
  Promise.all(msg.args().map(e => e.jsonValue()))
    .then(args => console.log(...args));

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  page.on("console", onPageConsole);
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener("load", event => {
      console.log("Loaded!");
    });
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "load"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If all you're trying to do is run some code in the browser after load, then you might not even need to attach a listener to the load event at all:

```js
const onPageConsole = msg =>
  Promise.all(msg.args().map(e => e.jsonValue()))
    .then(args => console.log(...args));

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  page.on("console", onPageConsole);
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "load"});
  await page.evaluate(() => console.log("Loaded!"));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Or if the code you want to run is purely Node just use normal control flow:

```js
let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {waitUntil: "load"});
  console.log("Loaded!");
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

By the way, there's no need to make a function `async` unless you have `await` in it somewhere.

See also [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72537739#72537739).