# Playwright Wait for Page to completely load and XHR / Ajax Calls complete

Tags: playwright-sharp

I have previously used Puppeteer in Node.js and I am now using Microsoft.Playwright in .Net

I have a need to wait until all XHR / Ajax requests have finished so that the page is in a truly "ready" state.  Using timouts and delays is unreliable.

With Puppeteer I used a library Pending XHR Puppeteer https://www.npmjs.com/package/pending-xhr-puppeteer which was designed for this issue specifically

So in node.js I would load the page etc inside a warapper and then when needed I would just call

```
await pageWrapper.waitForAllXhrFinished()
```

I am assuming that behind the scenes it is keeping count of the ajax requests sent and returning the function once they have all returned.

Note:  for one of my scenarios there are 2 XHR requests set and they are from exactly the same URL.

How can we achieve this in Playwright for .Net ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535642/6243352) which is agnostic of any browser automation. [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#when-is-the-page-loaded) say: "Modern pages perform numerous activities after the load event was fired. They fetch data lazily, populate UI, load expensive resources, scripts and styles after the load event was fired. There is no way to tell that the page is loaded, it depends on the page, framework, etc." Inevitably, waiting for network idle relies on timeouts (no network requests in N milliseconds).

Answer (score 9):

**Dotnet:**

`await popup.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.Networkidle)`

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state

**JS:**

`await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle")`

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state

Answer (score 4):

Using `await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.NetworkIdle);` didn't work for me in my Blazor Server App.

[According to the documentation](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state)

> Optional load state to wait for, defaults to load. If the state has
> been already reached while loading current document, the method
> resolves immediately. Can be one of:
>
> ```
> 'load' - wait for the load event to be fired.
> 'domcontentloaded' - wait for the DOMContentLoaded event to be fired.
> 'networkidle' - DISCOURAGED wait until there are no network connections for at least 500 ms. Don't use this method for testing,
> ```
>
> rely on web assertions to assess readiness instead.

Neither did the default: `await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync();` or the `await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.DOMContentLoaded);`

These likely work better when you aren't writing a SPA.

If you are specifically waiting on a popup, use:

[await Page.RunAndWaitForPopupAsync()](https://await%20Page.RunAndWaitForPopupAsync())