# How to make Puppeteer wait for JavaScript script tags to finish loading so that it can take a screenshot?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to take a screenshot of an iframe from a local HTML file using the Puppeteer library. The way it works is that I would use a some script tags in an HTML file below:

```
 <script src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, the screenshot turns out to be blank or have a gray or blue rectangle in place of instead of rendering the proper iframe (I've attached a picture below). How can I get the iframe to finish loading, then make Puppeteer to take the screenshot?

This is the result of the screenshot: [image]

My code is below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const process = require('process');
const fs = require('fs');
 
const htmlWithParameters = () => {
    return (
        `
        <script src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        `
    )
}
 
const createMapWithHTML = async () => {
    var html = htmlWithParameters()
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("progressionofshiptraffic.html");
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        stream.write(html);
        stream.end();
    });
}
 
(async () => {
    await createMapWithHTML()
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3703.0 Safari/537.36')
    await page.goto("file://" + process.cwd() + "/" + "shiptrafficprogression.html")
    //await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
    await page.screenshot({path: "image.png"})
    await browser.close(
 
})();
```

Comment: A simple solution to this problem is to just wait a fixed amount of seconds. (see [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/12101554)) This isn't the best solution, and there probably is a better way, but if you follow KISS (keep it simple, stupid) this will work for now

Answer (score 0):

A great solution would be to add the `waitUntill` option in the got to call. I can see you tried to use it in the `waitForNavigation` but it should probably be in the `goto()` instead

You can use the following:

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
```

Reference:
https://thewebdev.info/2022/05/30/how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded-with-puppeteer-and-javascript/

If your navigating to another page and you need to wait for it to load you can use the `waitForNavigation`  function with the wait until option.

If you need to wait on an element to be visible you can use the `page.waitForSelector()`:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#example', {
  visible: true,
});
```

Reference: [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded)

Comment: Still the same issue- the screenshot ends up completely blank when viewed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await page.waitForResponse`, see https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforresponse