# Programatically detect client rendered sites

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, server-side-rendering, cheerio

I'm building a web scrapper and currently I'm using puppeteer to extract the content. But the problem with puppeteer is that it takes a lot of ram and sometimes my server runs out of memory when I scrap 15+ pages simultaneously.

So, I'm thinking about using cheerio for server rendered sites. I'm hoping it will be a lot faster and less expensive to user cheerio.

Is there any way to tell if a website is client rendered or not?

Comment: The simple answer is: look at `view-source:` and see if the elements you want are there. But it's not so simple in general: sometimes with SPAs, the data is still statically scrapable via the source or via an HTTP API request that you can hit without Puppeteer. Sharing the actual site and a list of the output data is the only way to say for sure, since there are many possible cases. Also, there are ways to improve Puppeteer's efficiency and reduce memory consumption even if you can't switch to fetch/cheerio.

Comment: view-source:? how can I check view-source using axios/fetch or cheerio?
Also I don't know exactly what the webpages looks like. I just want to extract the content from a bunch of unrealted sites.

Comment: With axios/fetch, simply print the response text--that's basically the same as `view-source:` unless the server responds with something different based on the requesting user agent or other HTTP headers. "I just want to extract the content from a bunch of unrealted sites" is sort of like asking "I just want an interview strategy that will get me any job". Every site is different and there is no silver bullet, so you'll need to spec it out a bit more than this. Even if your goal is to just print the general HTML of each site, waiting for SPA loading across all sites is not necessarily trivial.

Comment: [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72535642#72535642) is my canonical response to this situation.

Comment: currently I'm using puppeteer and it's working fine the only problem is it takes a lot of memory. So I would like to use something like cheerio only on server rendered sites.

Comment: @ggorlen can you tell me what I should search for in the text which can be used to determine if a page is SPA or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way to determine whether something is an SPA or not, and more context about what you're trying to accomplish is necessary. In fact, many sites aren't SPAs and don't use React/Angular/Vue/etc but the data you may want is nonetheless loaded asynchronously by JS. Start with your high-level goal, like "I'm trying to collect training data for an LLM and need to scrape any paragraphs on random websites that contain the text 'Metallica'" or whatever it is you're trying to achieve. Then we can analyze how to get there, but chances are the above link is going to stand.

Comment: You could search the text for "react", "vue", "angular" etc, but this could cause all kinds of issues. What if it's a totally static news site with the text "Politicians react to budget cuts". Now you need to only scan scripts for the text, all of which would need to be requested. Then there are dozens/hundreds other frameworks to test which is the long tail beyond the popular frameworks. You probably get the idea--no silver bullet.

Comment: ahh, thank you for the response, 
so my best option is to keep using puppeeter to make sure everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @ggorlen there's no way to determine whether a site is using ssr or csr and the best option is to use puppeteer.