# Read dynamic page content from a website page using Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to fetch dynamic div content which is loading after a few seconds from a website page URL using Puppeteer. But the dynamic content text is not getting using the puppeteer. The website page contains a div, ie  and i would like to get the inside the division. If we directly load the page in the browser it will show that status after a few seconds ( there should be some external calls to get and show that status in that div element) but if call it using puppeteer, the content is getting empty. Any idea? Is not possible to fetch the dynamic contents using Puppeteer? The following code is currently using

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            await page.goto("<URL>/status.html", { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let results = [];
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('div');

                items.forEach((item) => {
                    results.push({
                        url:  item.getAttribute('id'),
                        text: item.innerText,
                    });
                });
                return results;
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Also, what's the page? There are many reasons why content might not be selectable--timing, iframe presence, shadow DOM, you being detected as a bot and blocked, wrong selector, etc. Also possibly relevant: [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72535642#72535642)

Comment: @ggorlen, Thanks for the update. It was because of request was blocked on the server side. So, i have set the user agent and now it starts working. Thank you :)