# Why won't puppeteer select a button

Tags: puppeteer

Simple program open up page, click on a button.  Page opens fine but I can't get to the button.  How do I get to the button?  BTW the class is correct and JQUERY finds the button using the dev window.

evetime I use puppeteer it's take hours for each step, getting code to click a button should take 30 second, what is going on?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})


    await page.goto('https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/', {waitUntil: 'load'});
    await navigationPromise;

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".fdx-c-navbar__menu__item__button");

        return Array.from(elements).map(element => element.tagName);
    });

    console.log(result);

console.log(result);
```

PRINT OUT:
C:\WebApps\Web Scrapper>node app
App listening on port 8080
Press Ctrl+C to quit.
FX
784543942889
10000
start FXScrap
recordCount: 1
*
[
'HTML',                 'HEAD',        'META',
'LINK',                 'TITLE',       'BASE',
'META',                 'META',        'META',
'META',                 'META',        'META',
'META',                 'META',        'META',
'LINK',                 'SCRIPT',      'SCRIPT',
'SCRIPT',               'SCRIPT',      'SCRIPT',
'LINK',                 'SCRIPT',      'SCRIPT',
'LINK',                 'SCRIPT',      'SCRIPT',
'SCRIPT',               'BODY',        'DIV',
'FEDEX-COOKIE-CONSENT', 'FEDEX-ALERT', 'DIV',
'APP-ROOT',             'SCRIPT',      'SCRIPT',
'SCRIPT',               'SCRIPT',      'NOSCRIPT',
'SCRIPT',               'DIV',         'SCRIPT',
'IFRAME',               'DIV'
]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, a query working in dev tools doesn't give any guarantee it'll work in Puppeteer. Dev tools waits for the page to load, expands iframes and shadow roots and bypasses bot detectors, things that aren't always done by default in browser automation.

Here are a few issues in your attempt:

1. Some sites block the page from loading if you're detected as a robot. [Add a user agent or run headfully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352) as a first attempt to circumvent this.
2. [Use `"domcontentloaded"` as the load event](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded), generally alongside `page.waitForSelector()`.
3. [Don't use `page.waitForNavigation()` along with `page.goto()`](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation). `page.goto()` already waits for navigation, so it's redundant and possibly a race condition to call it again.

Putting these together:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const btn = await page.waitForSelector("text/Track Another Shipment");
  await btn.click();
  const input = await page.waitForSelector('[id^="tracking_number_"]');
  await input.type("12345");
  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog posts.</sub>

Comment: OMG thanks!!!! You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

added this and seems to be working now:
await page.waitForSelector('#content', { timeout: 5_000 });

WTF is the point of this:

```
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
await page.goto('https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/', {waitUntil: 'load'});
        await navigationPromise;
```

if it doesn't wait until the page is fully loaded?

Comment: `goto` already waits for navigation, so there's no need for an extra `waitForNavigation` call. See [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72535642#72535642)--there is no such single thing as "fully loaded" since pages can make resource requests at any time. [`"load"` only waits for the browser load event](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded), not all resources. If you're waiting for a button, wait for the button specifically, not everything else.

Comment: That is what I thought, thanks for clarifying!

I tried doing waiting for the button, but it never seems to work, It always just timed out, even when the timeout it large.  If I put in a wait statement first for some amount of time, hope it waits long enough, then it sees the button (same selectors used in both cases).