Why is the iframe not loading in puppeteer?
const iframeElementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
//
console.log(0);
await iframeElementHandle.waitForSelector('iframe');
//
console.log(1);

after waitForSelector the code doesn't want to happen further
I need to load an iframe and then manage my js code inside the iframe.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1361 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded might be helpful?

no it's not that

Please share a [mcve] and the page under test. The code here is 100% fine, so either you're being blocked, picking the wrong selectors, not respecting JS timing, not traversing a shadow root, or one of many other possibilities.

const iframeElementHandle = await page.$('iframe'); 
const contentFrame = await iframeElementHandle.contentFrame();
await contentFrame.waitForSelector('iframe');


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
