# Puppeteer Screenshot full page omitting background images

Tags: puppeteer

HI Ive been trying to get puppeteer to take a screenshot of full pages, including all images.  Unfortunately background images are getting omitted (see comparison below)... I can't figure out how to get them.

Here's my code

```js
async function screeshotFullPage(url: string): Promise<string> {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const selectors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img"));

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160929/puppeteer-wait-for-all-images-to-load-then-take-screenshot

    await document.body.scrollIntoView(false);
    await Promise.all(
      selectors.map((img) => {
        if (img.complete) return;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          img.addEventListener("load", resolve);
          img.addEventListener("error", reject);
        });
      })
    );
  });

  await sleep(5000); // resolves in 5 sec

  const path = generateScreenshotPath();

  await page.screenshot({
    path,
    fullPage: true,
  });

  return await browser.close();
}

await screeshotFullPage("https://chesskid.com")
```

[image: no background images]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but I had troubles with CSS backgrounds in PDFs generated by Puppeteer if they were direct links to S3 files. Switching links to CloudFront (Amazon's CDN) fixed the issue for me.